# 6sec latency dragging a few images in Explorer, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, latency

Recently bought a second hand Thinkpad P51, and did a clean install of Windows 10. Compared to Windows 7 on far inferior laptops, Windows 10 and Explorer specially is extremely sluggish. To drag 10 png images (3mb total) into a folder it takes 6 sec from drop until the images visually move.

What may cause this and how to proceed?

LatencyMon:   [image]

EDIT:

It seems **LTSpice XII** being installed on this computer was the issue. Just deleted it, and latency so far is gone.

Comment: The ThinkPad PSFEF says it supports Windows 10.  Install Lenovo System Update and install all drivers including BIOS.

Comment: I posted an answer, will you find that helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled **LTSpice XII**, and the latency stopped, even without a restart. Not sure if **LTSpice** had auto-start processes running in background. But it's possible it has some form of integration with Explorer, since during uninstall I got this message to close all invocations of Windows Explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please see here:

[ThinkPad P51 PSREF](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_P51/ThinkPad_P51_Spec.PDF)

This machine supports Windows 10

> Operating system One of the following, configurable by model:
> • Windows 7 Professional 64  preinstalled through downgrade rights in
> Windows 10 Pro 64 •   Windows 10 Home 64 •   Windows 10 Pro 64 • Windows
> 10 Pro 64 for Workstation

Use the Lenovo System Updater to update all Drivers including BIOS.

If this does not work and since the machine is second hand, get a Windows 10 Install ISO, back up the machine, and reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: Updated only Bios. Was not using latest version. This fixed the latency issue.

Comment: Latency returned. Must have been the restart that fixed it temporarily. So I unchecked this answer..

Comment: I suggest you back up the (second hand) machine, and do a fresh install of Windows 10.  Answer amended.